# Parallel algorithms O(log p)

Tags: theory, parallel-processing

First off this isn't for any homework question, it's just on a general type of algorithm. In a parallel computing course I'm taking I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a style of algorithm that has runtime O( something + ... log p). For example we've looked at sequence reduction algorithms that are O(n/p + log p) where p = #procs and n is problem size. Log base 2.

The problem I have is the idea of log(p). For one I'm used to seeing log(n) everywhere in reducing problems to two subproblems of size n/2 etc. The second is just the idea of having the step complexity of an algorithm as log(p). Because that would imply that for a problem of fixed size if I increase the number of processors then I am increasing the number of steps in the algorithm? I have always thought of the step complexity of an algorithm as the sort of inherent sequential aspect of the algorithm and hence increasing or decreasing the number of processors shouldn't have any effect on this. Is this a bad way to think of it?

I guess what would be helpful is some pseudocode of algorithms that have log(p) running time somewhere in them.

Comment: "where p = #procs" sorry, should have put that at the top

Comment: How huge is p. Is it about real systems (up to 32), huge real systems (up to 1k or 200-300 k for top supercomputer) or theoretical (p is unlimited)

Comment: Just strictly theoretical. No notions of overhead due to thread creation or communication across nodes or anything.

Comment: Can you give us an example of an algorithm with that running time?  Looking at an actual algorithm will help us point out where that factor comes from.  Outside of that, log(p) factors like that tend to arise from dissemination of the input to all processors and amalgamation of the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider computing the sum of n numbers.  Each processor can be assigned n/p numbers, but how do you add up the results from the individual processors?  You could pass all p results to one processor, for a runtime O(n/p+p), but you can combine the sums faster in a tree-like fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that O(n/p + log(p)) does make sense, because n/p + log(p) it's decreasing at the increasing of the p variable, so the running time decrease as you add processors and this bound does make sense; otherwise a running time of log(p) isn't likely to be natural because it's decreasing in respect to the processors number.